# Screenshot from WPF application as SVG / vector graphic?

Tags: wpf, svg, screenshot, zooming

is it possible to create a screenshot of a WPF application as SVG / is there some WPF built-in function to get the XAML code for the current drawn window that then can be converted to SVG? I need some screenshots for documenting a WPF application and I'd like them to be zoomable like a WPF program is using e.g. Snoop or Vista Magnifyer. Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to use XamlWriter to serialize the XAML, and then write or find an implementation of something to convert that to the vector format of choice.

Comment: Thank you Jeff. One can use Inkscape to open the XAML and save it in another format.